# error: undefined reference to `SignbotController::establish_pub(ros::NodeHandle)'

Tags: c++, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I am having trouble finding the solution for this error. I known it is a linker error, but when i look at the /devel i found that  the libsignbotcontroll.so exists. So i dont get why i'm getting this.

I am working on ubuntu 14.04 and ros indigo.

Heres my signbot_controll.h

```
#ifndef _SIGNBOT_CONTROLL_
#define _SIGNBOT_CONTROLL_

#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/String.h"

#include "trajectory_msgs/JointTrajectory.h"

 class SignbotController
 {
   private:
       ros::Publisher body_controll_pub;     //topic which will control the model in gazebo
       trajectory_msgs::JointTrajectory _message;

       void insert_jointnames();
   public:

        void establish_pub(ros::NodeHandle n);

        void publish();
  };
  #endif
```

Here's my signbot_control.cpp:

```
#include  <signbot_plugins/signbot_controll.h>

 void SignbotController::establish_pub(ros::NodeHandle n)
{
   //code ...
}

void SignbotController::insert_jointnames()
{
   //code ...
 }

 void SignbotController::publish()
 {
     ROS_INFO_STREAM("asd");
 }
```

Here's my main.cpp:

```
#include <signbot_plugins/signbot_controll.h>

 int main(int argc, char **argv)
 {
   ros::init(argc, argv, "signbot_core");
   ros::NodeHandle nh;

   SignbotController sigcon;

   sigcon.establish_pub(nh);

   if(ros::ok())
   {
     ros::spin();
   }

    ROS_INFO_STREAM("\n\t***** SHUTTING DOWN ********\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

Here's my cmakelist.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(signbot_plugins)

## Find catkin macros and libraries
## if COMPONENTS list like find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS xyz)
## is used, also find other catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  roscpp
  trajectory_msgs)

###################################
## catkin specific configuration ##
###################################
## The catkin_package macro generates cmake config files for your package
## Declare things to be passed to dependent projects
## INCLUDE_DIRS: uncomment this if you package contains header files
## LIBRARIES: libraries you create in this project that dependent projects also need
## CATKIN_DEPENDS: catkin_packages dependent projects also need
## DEPENDS: system dependencies of this project that dependent projects also need
catkin_package(
INCLUDE_DIRS include
LIBRARIES signbot_plugins
CATKIN_DEPENDS
      message_runtime
      roscpp
      trajectory_msgs
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

###########
## Build ##
###########

## Specify additional locations of header files
## Your package locations should be listed before other locations
include_directories(
 include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

## Declare a C++ library
 add_library(classtranslator src/classtranslator.cpp)
 add_library(signbotcontroll src/signbot_controll.cpp)

## Add cmake target dependencies of the library
## as an example, code may need to be generated before libraries
## either from message generation or dynamic reconfigure
  add_dependencies(classtranslator ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
  add_dependencies(signbotcontroll ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

  target_link_libraries(classtranslator ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
  target_link_libraries(signbotcontroll ${catkin_LIBRARIES})

  add_executable(signbot_core_node src/signbot_core.cpp)
  add_dependencies(signbot_core_node signbot_core_cpp)
  target_link_libraries(signbot_core_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270394/error:-undefined-reference-to-%60signbotcontroller::establish_pub(ros::nodehandle)%27/) by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 137 on 2017-09-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found out my error. It was in the CMakeList.txt file.

I have this:

```
  target_link_libraries(signbot_core_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

and it should be like this:

```
  target_link_libraries(signbot_core_node signbotcontroll ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [FábioBarbosa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29070/f%C3%A1biobarbosa/) with karma: 137 on 2017-09-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-07**:
Suggestion: if there is no need to make `classtranslator` and `signbotcontroll` libraries, then just add all of them as source entries to your `signbot_core_node` binary:

```
add_executable(signbot_core_node
  src/signbot_core.cpp
  src/classtranslator.cpp
  src/signbot_controll.cpp)
```